# who is Rabbi Menashe Klein referring to (a "religious" psychologist who wrote a forbidden book)?

Tags: story-identification, responsa

[Rabbi Menashe Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menashe_Klein) in Sefer Bais Rahel on [page 144](http://www.tshuvos.com/pdf/beisrachel.pdf#page=143) when discussing the dangers of psychologists (marriage counselors) says:

> וכבר נשמע על אחד מהם שכינה עצמו רב ודתי וחרדי מאד מאד, שכתב כביכול ספר [פסול] הדרכה בעניני אישות ואף קיבל הסכמות, ובעניותי יצאתי אז נגדו ונגד הספר פסול שכתב, וב''ה וב''ש שבעוד לא זמן רב נתגלה קלונו ברבים ונאסר ע''י הממשלה במאסר על שעשה מיני נבלות, שלא יאומן כי יסופר.‏

That is, one person who called himself a very religious Rav wrote a book about marital relations and received approbations, and I (Rav Menashe Klein) opposed him and his book, thank G-d his disgrace was publicised and he was imprisoned by the government.

who can this be (the man, the book) referring to?

Comment: i do not know what to tag it, i appreciate corrections

Comment: Do you think it might be lashon hara to know who the rabbi is talking about? That seems pretty embarrassing for that doctor.

Comment: @ezra for me i think it is l'toeles

Comment: You sure? Because if he went to jail the chances are he's probably not writing any more books that could harm you.

Comment: @ezra L'shon hara is where one's goal is to mock someone or demean them; not when one has some ulterior motive. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81491/8775. Also depending on what this person did, he is likely not included in עמיתך, and depending, it is likely a דבר מפורסם. Lastly, there is a toelet for hazoriz to know which book is being referred to.

Comment: When did he write this and what government imprisoned the writer and for what crime?

Comment: @sabbahillel all I know is Bais Rahel is marked as published in 2008

Comment: @ezra one whould be to see what psychological books Rav Klein considered posul

Comment: @sabbahillel but  I would guess 90% USA 10% Israel

Comment: But what crime would he have been arrested for, and how would it have anything to do with the book? In any case, it should be closed as not involving Judaism.

Comment: @sabbahillel being arrested is not what I am interested in,  I want to learn more about this to have a healthier (Jewisher) aproch to jewish religious psychologist and there books and marriage advice

Comment: @sabbahillel That is incorrect. A book by someone known as a rabbi about a Jewish related topic, is certainly on topic. Identifying which book is referred to is thus on topic. Asking what exactly the author did would not necessarily be on topic.